# Determine the convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt k - 2\sqrt {k + 1} + \sqrt {k + 2} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

I'm having trouble determining the convergence of the series:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt k - 2\sqrt {k + 1} + \sqrt {k + 2} 
$$

I am thinking it doesn't converge and since neither the root test or $$|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}|$$ seemed to work for me I would have to use a comparing test

Keep in mind I am not allowed to actually calculate what it converges to.

Comment: It telescopes${}$.

Comment: it should give me something like $\sqrt{1} - \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{n +2} - \sqrt{n+1}$ but how does that help me determine the convergence?

Comment: @John.Doh: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}\right]$$ is finite.

Comment: The problem is yes while it seems like a duplicate. I can not use the telescope method because I have to determine whether or not it converges by not actually calculating to what it converges(if it converges). Hence the solutions given there are invalid for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an outline of a solution:

Notice that

$$\sqrt{k} - 2 \sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k + 2} = \sqrt{k + 2} - \sqrt{k + 1} - \big(\sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt{k}\big)$$

is the difference between the right- and left- hand estimates for the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ at $k + 1$. This has a lot in common with the second derivative of $\sqrt{x}$, which is of the order $x^{-3/2}$. Hence, you may find it very useful to compare your series with

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$$

which is easily seen to converge.

---

Alternatively, as pointed out in comments, the series telescopes.

Comment: but isn't it $$\sqrt{k} - 2 \sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k + 2} = \sqrt{k + 2} - \sqrt{k + 1} - \big(-\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k + 1}\big)$$ ?

Comment: Yes, a typo. The point is the same, though.

Comment: @user296602: but the derivative of root $x$ is $\frac{1}{2x^{1/2}}$.

Comment: @daulomb Yes, but this is a *second* difference, which is related to the second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

For real $0 < x < 1,$ you can check, by squaring, that
$$ 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} < \sqrt{1+x} <  1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{x^3}{16}  $$
You can get the same information from the first few terms of the Taylor series, with explicit remainder.

Using $x = 1/k$ and $x = 2/k$ gives
$$ \sqrt k \left( - \frac{1}{4 k^2} \right) < \sqrt k - 2 \sqrt {k+1} + \sqrt {k+2} <  \sqrt k \left( - \frac{1}{4 k^2} +  \frac{3}{8 k^3}  \right),  $$
$$ - \frac{1}{4 k^{3/2}}  < \sqrt k - 2 \sqrt {k+1} + \sqrt {k+2} < - \frac{1}{4 k^{3/2}}  +  \frac{3}{8 k^{5/2}}  \; \; .  $$
When $k \geq 2,$ we get
$$ - \frac{1}{4 k^{3/2}}  < \sqrt k - 2 \sqrt {k+1} + \sqrt {k+2} < 0 \; \; .  $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{k} - 2 \sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k + 2} = \color{red}{\sqrt{k + 2} - \sqrt{k + 1}} - \big(\color{blue}{\sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt{k}}\big)$$

By Telescoping sum we get,

$$ \sum^n_{k=1}\sqrt{k} - 2 \sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k + 2}= =\sqrt{n + 2}-\sqrt{2} -(\sqrt{n+1} -1)  =\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 2}+\sqrt{n + 1 }}+1-\sqrt{ 2}$$

$$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\sqrt{k} - 2 \sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k + 2} =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 2}+\sqrt{n + 1 }}+1-\sqrt{ 2}= \color{blue}{1-\sqrt{ 2}}$$

Comment: what about the middle terms such as $-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{4},-\sqrt{5},..$ etc. as I can see they dont disapper

Comment: @daulomb all the term are included in that why do yoibwant to somewhere else?